# How to use async loaded assets in sagas with react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, redux-saga, tensorflow.js

I am building an Expo app using redux-saga and tensorflow js. The model has to be loaded async when initializing the app. In all the examples, the model is loaded in a component and stored in the component's state.

I would like however to perform inference in a saga and not directly in the component.

I don't know how to write the initialization process so as to be able to access the loaded model from within the saga.

In `App.js` I have the following:

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoadingComplete: false,
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
          onError={this._handleLoadingError}
          onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
        />
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
           .....
        </Provider>
      )
    }
```

and I have put init and warmup code for the model from [tfjs doc](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.0.0/#loadGraphModel) in `this._loadResourcesAsync`:

```js
  _loadResourcesAsync = async () => {
    await Promise.all([
      Asset.loadAsync([
        require('./assets/images/splash.png'),
        require('./assets/images/icon.png'),
      ]),
      Font.loadAsync({
        ...Icon.MaterialIcons.font,
        ...Icon.MaterialCommunityIcons.font,
        ...Icon.FontAwesome.font,
        ...Icon.Feather.font,
      }),
      tf.ready(),
    ])
    const modelUrl = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224/model.json';
    const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(modelUrl);
    const zeros = tf.zeros([1, 224, 224, 3]);
    model.predict(zeros).print();
  };
```

I don't know how to access this model in a saga later on.

### EDIT

After @senthil recommendation of using Singleton pattern, I have try to place this code either in an separate file or directly in the `_loadResourcesAsync` but it makes the app crash

```js
const modelUrl = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224/model.json';

let instance;

async function createInstance() {
  console.log("createInstance")
  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(modelUrl);
  console.log("model", model)
  // Warm-up
  const zeros = tf.zeros([1, 224, 224, 3]);
  console.log("zeros", zeros)
  model.predict(zeros).print();
  return {model}
}

async function getInstance() {
  console.log("getInstance")
  console.log("instance", instance)
  if (!instance) {
    instance = await createInstance();
  }
  return instance;
}

const {model} = await getInstance()
console.log("encoder", model)
```

In the logs I see that the code gets stuck in `const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(modelUrl);`

Comment: I think you have to use singleton pattern here. on App-loading create an instance of the loaded model and uses it across the application, even in sagas.

Comment: @senthilbalaji thanks for the reco. I have tried to make this work and update the question accordingly but it makes the app crash. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to maintain state for this case, like in

```js
// let's assume, this is your App.js
import MLModel from "./MLModel";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoadingComplete: false,
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={async () => { 
             await this._loadOtherResources();
             MLModel.loadModel(() => {
                this.setState({isLoadingComplete:true});
             })
           }}
          onError={this._handleLoadingError}
          onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
        />
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
           .....
        </Provider>
      )
    }
```

in your MLModel.js

```js
// MlModel.js file should have a class

class MLModel {
   let model = null;

   getModel(){
     return this.model;
   }

   async loadModel(onModelLoadCompleteCallback) {
    const modelUrl = '<URL>';
    const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(modelUrl);
    // I'm not sure what'll below line do exactly like mutate or return
    // I'm assuming this is async and will mutate the model object.
    await model.predict(zeros).print();
    this.model = model;
    onModelLoadCompleteCallback();
   }
}

export default new MLMoldel();
```

In the same way, you should be able to load the model from every other place as well.

Note: I haven't executed and checked, may have some compile error ignore them but ultimately this is something I'm trying to convey.

Comment: Okj I'ill try! and why do you need a `onModelLoadCompleteCallback` and cannot just `await loadModel` in `App.js`?

Comment: you could do that as well. The above example is mainly for how to create & reuse the `singleton pattern`.

Comment: works great thanks. Since I have several models, I have put in `models/index.js` the base `MLModel` class and then created one file per model inheriting from `MLModel` and overriding the `url` arg.

Comment: Glad it helped. you might also have to cache your models locally otherwise every AppStart will be delayed as it has to download everytime.

Comment: yes but there is currently a limitation with tfjs, managed expo app and local VS remote model.json assets. Hopefully it will change soon